# file_get_contents() error

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using file_get_contents on my PHP and it throws some errors:

My code

```
#try to fetch from remote
$this->remotePath = "http://some-hostname.com/blah/blah.xml
$fileIn = @file_get_contents($this->remotePath);
```

The errors:

```
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /virtual/path/to/file/outputFile.php on line 127

Warning: file_get_contents(https://some-host-name/data/inputFile.xml) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /virtual/path/to/file/outputFile.php on line 127
```

Any idea? It worked fine in my computer but stopped working when I ported it to the web server.

Comment: Btw, since you want to load xml, use the function simplexml_load_file, after setting up allow_url_fopen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your server must have the [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) property set to true. Being on a free webhost explains it, as it's usually disabled to prevent abuse. If you paid for your hosting, get in contact with your host so they can enable it for you.

If changing that setting is not an option, then have a look at the [cURL](http://php.net/curl) library.

Comment: Do you know any way to work around that because that file is from a remote server, not from my internal server.

Comment: You might get away with doing it on your own via
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1)
but there's a good chance that's locked down as well.

Comment: My host set `allow_url_fopen` to off but enabled `curl`. In how far does that make sense (from their perspective)?

Answer (score 5):

It seems "allow_url_fopen" setting is false on your server and hence does not allow using URLs with file_get_contents().

Try using [CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php) instead that is a better and efficient way of communicating with other server.