# PHP validate image url

Tags: php, image, verification

I have this very simple form. It's for people who want to give their selves a "profile picture" on my website. No upload, just put the url of your image and click save. So, it's just a "url".

This is my current code

```
<?PHP 
    if(is_array(getimagesize($_POST['profilepicture']))&&filter_var($_POST['profilepicture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL,FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED)){    
        echo "Good";
    } else {
        echo "Bad";
    }
?>
```

I have tried everything. I've tried just getimagesize() and it doesn't work. This works on my localhost via wamp, but fails on my host. Do I have to have something in my php.ini changed?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Would you mind posting what your form looks like that is being POSTed?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your host might not have the [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) directive enabled. This might cause the situation where external url's image not to be accessed by the `getimagesize` function. If that is the case turning on error reporting will throw a warning stating

> Warning:
> getimagesize(http://extenalsite.com/path/to/profile/image.txt)
> [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper
> could be found

and setting it on would help the cause. Refer similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652465/trying-to-turn-on-allow-url-fopen-by-putting-php-ini-in-wordpress-root-does-not)

Answer (score 0):

Check your ["upload_max_filesize"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) definition in your PHP.ini folder. Make sure it is not failing the upload procedure. (Any files larger than the default 2MB will be cancelled.)

For reference check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263480/upload-max-size-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem. I checked out my error log on my host. It said allow_url_fopen=0 was the error. I turned it "On" on my php.ini, and now it works!