# POST data to URL with cURL after login

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use PHP/cURL to POST data to a URL where being logged in is required.  From the PHP code I can execute the login successfully, but when I do the next POST, the site responds that I am not logged in.  Any idea as to how the site determines that the login is no longer active for the second POST?  One of the POST options for the login is "Remember me from this machine" which I have set.  Here is the partial code:

```
//#### Log IN

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = curl_init('http://www.website.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $log_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//#####  Second POST to send data

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;  Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
```

Comment: PHP's cURL library has an awful API. But you can try to run tcpflow tool (`apt-get install tcpflow`) and listen on what you send out from your browser. You may analyse the POST you send and you'll see which headers you're missing. I guess that you're missing one particular authentication header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the the cookie.
When you post to login, a session cookie or something would be set, you need to resend that cookie with the next request. Luckily it's pretty easy.

Check out [PHP Curl And Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885538/php-curl-and-cookies)