# file_get_contents works in php7.2 but not in php7.3 or 7.4

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-7.3

This works in php7.2

```
$contents = file_get_contents('https://somesite.com/banpost.php', false, $context);

echo $contents;
```

but when I switch to 7.3 or 7.4 the page doesn't show.

Comment: Is it getting an error? Do you have `fopen_url` enabled?

Comment: Thank you. That got it solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Server configuration by allow\_url\_fopen=0 in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677579/server-configuration-by-allow-url-fopen-0-in)