# How to fetch/Redirect to the next page after sending post request using cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

This code given below is sending the correct post request. Problem is, whenever is assign incorrect  username and password to  `uname` and `pword` respectively is shows the correct output which '`singin1.php`' page with the message '`Wrong Username or Password`"(stored in `$result`) but when correct username and password are provided, it shown me the same 'signin1.php' page. It does not show me the authorized screen which i should get after logging in.

```
<?php
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://computerinfo.in/school/signin1.php';

$fields = array(
                        'uname' => 'username',
            'pword' => 'password',
            'submt' => 'Submit'
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string[]= $key.'='.$value;}
$fields_items = implode ('&', $fields_string);


//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
//fname%3Dasdf%26lname%3Dsdafasdf%26lolz%3DSubmit
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_items);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "<br>Field Item= "."<br>";
echo $result."=Result"."</br>";


echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br>' . 
            curl_error($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I want to know if i am missing something in order to get the next screen , which i should see after normal log in. 
The above code is present at http://computerinfo.in/school/test.php
and code with correct username and password is present at http://computerinfo.in/school/test1.php

and link of sign in page is http://computerinfo.in/school/signin1.php

Structure of  `signin.php`

```
    if(isset($_POST['submt']))
    {

        if(uname && pword are correct)
        {
            //creating session using session_start();  and redirection using header;
        }
        else
        {           
            $message="Wrong Username or Password";
        }
```

`signin.php` is working fine , if i am providing username and password manually.

Comment: The code, probably, relies on sessions. Store and use session cookie, make initial request to load the page with form, get cookie, use it with posted data.

Comment: Yups , I have added the abstract code for signin1.php page also in question.... 
get cookies and using it with posted data... can you give a hint how to do it , or any tutorial.... I am new to cURL. Thank You

Comment: `and redirection using header;` you have to tell CURL to follow the redirection. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`, but still, in order to work with sessions you have to store cookies.

Comment: Great, Now I can follow the redirection. Problem remains: how to get the cookies and can i store the cookies in browser, and log in to the system ?

Comment: Not sure why you want to store those cookies in browser. To store them and to use with curl look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885538/php-curl-and-cookies, for example.

Comment: Problem Solved (y). I working on something else, this example was to explain my problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As '`singin1.php`' page is using redirection with header, and session. It is compulsory to tell cURL to follow redirection and to fetch cookies.

To Follow redirection , this line should be added

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

and to fetch cookies and create session.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  'cookie.txt');
```

Final code for `test.php` will look like

```
<?php
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://computerinfo.in/school/signin1.php';

$fields = array(
                        'uname' => 'username',
            'pword' => 'password',
            'submt' => 'Submit'
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string[]= $key.'='.$value;}
$fields_items = implode ('&', $fields_string);


//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //NEW LINE
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_items);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); //NEW LINE
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  'cookie.txt'); // NEW LINE
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo "<br>Field Item= "."<br>";
echo $result."=Result"."</br>";


echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br>' . 
            curl_error($ch);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);

?>
```