# Set a cookie throught a require/include from another site

Tags: php, cookies, web, require

Is there a way to set a cookie throught a require from another website?

Lets say that I set on the first page of the following website "www.test.com" a require code like:

require('http://www.mycode.com.br/code.php');

And then make this require to set a cookie and perform some codes.
Is there a way to do this?

Facebook does that, but they set a cookie on their website that integrates with the user's website.
How can I perform something like this?

The "http://www.mycode.com.br/code.php" will also get the cookie and work with it to perform its actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) in particular [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Read this question as an example:

[PHP Curl And Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885538/php-curl-and-cookies)