# Can PHP store Cookie and send curl request using those cookie?

Tags: php, curl, cookies

We have 2 application run in 2 different server,
let say **SERVER_X** (PHP) and **SERVER_Y** (NODE).

In **SERVER_X** index.php

```
$url = 'http://10.10.10.2/login';
$poststring = 'username=admin&password=password';
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $poststring);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$url = 'http://10.10.10.2/getdata';
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo json_decode($output);
```

[image]
So what we want to achieve is by accessing SERVER_X/index.php, the **CLIENT** able to get the data from **SERVER_Y** where the authentication for **SERVER_Y** done in **SERVER_X** PHP code. Is this possible ?

Comment: `curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );` might be missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Curl And Cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885538/php-curl-and-cookies)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Manage to make it work with code below,

```
 define('_IP', '10.10.10.2');
define('_USERNAME', $_GET['user']);
define('_PASSWORD', $_GET['pass']);
define('_ORCHESTRA_PORT', '11111');
define('_NODE_PORT', '22222');

$main_auth_url = 'http://' . _IP . ':' . _ORCHESTRA_PORT . '/v2/auth/login';
$main_auth_credential = array("username" => _USERNAME, "password" => _PASSWORD);
$main_auth_credential = json_encode($main_auth_credential);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $main_auth_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $main_auth_credential);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$user_id = explode('set-cookie: userid=', $response);
$user_id = explode('; Max-Age', $user_id[1]);
$user_id = $user_id[0];

$token = explode('set-cookie: token=', $response);
$token = explode('; Max-Age', $token[1]);
$token = $token[0];

$connect_sid = explode('set-cookie: connect.sid=', $response);
$connect_sid = explode('; Path=/', $connect_sid[1]);
$connect_sid = $connect_sid[0];

$node_user_id = urldecode($user_id);
$node_user_id = explode('"', $node_user_id);
$node_user_id = $node_user_id[1];

$node_auth_url = 'http://' . _IP . ':' . _NODE_PORT . '/v2/auth/login';
$node_auth_credential = array("username" => $node_user_id, "password" => $token);
$node_auth_credential = json_encode($node_auth_credential);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $node_auth_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $node_auth_credential);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$connect_sid = explode('set-cookie: connect.sid=', $response);
$connect_sid = explode('; Path=/', $connect_sid[1]);
$connect_sid = $connect_sid[0];

$sub_url = 'http://' . _IP . ':' . _NODE_PORT . '/getdata';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sub_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: userid=" . $user_id . "; token=" . $token . "; connect.sid=" . $connect_sid));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre><hr>';
```