# Error when accessing youtube api: 'Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: URL > file-access is disabled...'

Tags: php, json, video, youtube

I was trying to follow this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3331372/1063287

So in my php document I had the variables below:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$video_id}?v=2&alt=json");
$json_data = json_decode($json);
$video_title = $json_data->{'entry'}->{'title'};
$video_date = $json_data->{'entry'}->{'published'};
$video_duration = $json_data->{'entry'}->{'media:group'}->{'yt$duration'};
$video_views = $json_data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
$video_description = $json_data->{'entry'}->{'content'};
```

but that gave me the error:

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: URL
>   file-access is disabled in the server configuration in
>   /home/path/to//file.php on line 12
>
> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xx-xxxxxxx?v=2&alt=json)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable
>   wrapper could be found in /home/path/to/file.php on line 12

I have looked at the developers guide here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php

and can understand the feed and entry structure here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds#Understanding_Video_Entries

and have found a few solutions (one involving curl) but they either haven't worked or I haven't known if they were the best method to use.

Can anyone please tell me if there is anything wrong in the above code?

Comment: check allow_url_fopen is ON or OFF in php.ini

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551379/file-get-contents-error check this out. If this might answer your query.

Comment: You can also try using cURL allows you to retrieve data to.

Comment: thank you all, host enabled allow_url_fopen and openssl and that error message went away, i have another one now but i think that is a coding issue `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`. so more homework to be done, thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because you do not have OpenSSL installed on your server. Try installing it, and if it still doesn't work it's probably because you have HTTP access disabled in your php.ini (set allow_url_fopen to true)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I saw for that is the `Zend_GData_Youtube` in the Zend Framework. It doesn't require anything special but it's much easier than a normal cURL or JSON request!

See there: http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest

Comment: thank you for your information, i'm not familiar with zend yet, but i'm sure this tip will be helpful to someone, thank you!