# PHP: How do I put server generated webcal content into a variable?

Tags: php, calendar, icalendar, webcal

I have this [link](https://ofriskole.viggo.dk/ExportCalendar/?ViggoId=45&UserId=336&code=f07825039276bcb028e59a87fa5afe90bd371ba9). When put in the browser, it seems to generate a file download named with current date, which is then downloaded.

Google Calendar can use this link to retrieve calendar events into my own calendar, but I need to parse the calendar using PHP.

My problem is not to make a parser, but PHP seems to get confused when I used the above link in a `file_get_contents()`. It states:

> failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in....

I can't seem to tackle this problem, and as it seems, others have not asked this specific question. I only found one about the Facebook webcal, which was also to no avail.

Comment: [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). I am sure if you search for the error message and/or your real problem, you will get lots of results even on this site or by using any we search engine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents() error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551379/file-get-contents-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get file\_get\_contents() work with HTTPS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-work-with-https)