# Json data in php returns null in live server

Tags: php, json

I am trying to fetch the data from the JSON, working as expected in localhost but it's not working in server. Even I tried with the JSON placeholder API.

PHP file

```
<?php $url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url); 
$obj = json_decode($jsondata, true);
var_dump($obj);
echo $obj[1]->title;
?>
```

I tried remove the true and tried with `$obj = json_decode($jsondata);` Still it returns null.

The same code working fine in my localhost.

Comment: Https and file_get_contents doesnt play well under some circumstances. Try wrapping that request with curl.

Comment: There may be a firewall at the hosting site that blocks it. Or PHP may have `fopen_url` disabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file\_get\_contents() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551379/file-get-contents-error)

Comment: i have enable the fopen_url = On Now its working as expected. Thank you @Barmar